# How to Stack elements from a 3D list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, vstack, hstack

I have two lists like these:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

y_all = [[2,3,5,4,6], 

         [3,2,4,3,5], 

         [4,5,4,3,4]]
```

And I need the output to be like this:

[(1, 2),
(2, 3),
(3, 5),
(4, 4),
(5, 6),
(1, 3),
(2, 2),
(4, 3),
(5, 5),
(1, 4),
(2, 5),
(3, 4),
(4, 3),
(5, 4),]

How can I do this more efficiently so that if I have a larger size of x and y_all I can do that?

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import numpy as np

y=np.array(y_all).T

y_all_fin = []

for i in range(len(y[0])):

    inter = np.vstack((x,y_all[i]))
    y_all_fin.append(inter)

points = np.hstack((y_all_fin[0],y_all_fin[1],y_all_fin[2])).T

N = []

for i in range(len(points[:,0])):

    new = tuple(points[i])

    N.append(new)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this simple 1-liner:

```
[a for y in y_all for a in zip(x,y)]
```

Note that there is little point using numpy if your arrays contain object (non numerical) types like tuples...